# Change component style without reloading the component

Tags: angular

I have an array of images gotten from parent component,
then push it as an input to child one and use it as background in child from first to last in arrange and can reorder them from child,
but the style doesn't apply only if I reload the page.

How can fix this?

[image: this is the child that use the array ass BG]

and this is implementation in parent taking the array as input
`<app-brand-header *ngIf="!hideHeader && theme != 'brand'" [images]="companyBrand.images"></app-brand-header>`

and this is the child ts file where I reorder from popup dialog.

```
export class BrandHeaderComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked {
    @Input() images: Image[] = [new Image()];
    
    editMode: boolean;
    
    companyBrand: Brand = new Brand();
    
    imagesPlaceholder: any[] = [
      { imageUrl: 'assets/images/gallery/placebolder_image_1.jpg' },
      { imageUrl: 'assets/images/gallery/placebolder_image_2.jpg' },
      { imageUrl: 'assets/images/gallery/placebolder_image_3.jpg' },
      { imageUrl: 'assets/images/gallery/placebolder_image_4.jpg' },
      { imageUrl: 'assets/images/gallery/placebolder_image_5.jpg' }
    ]

    constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      public dialog: MatDialog) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
        this.editMode = params.edit == 'true' ? true : false;
      });
      this.companyBrand = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('perePublic'));

    }

    ngAfterContentChecked() {
      if (this.companyBrand.images.length > 0) {
        this.images = this.companyBrand.images;
      } else {
        this.images = this.imagesPlaceholder;
      }
      this.images.sort(this.sortImgs)
    }

    rearrangeImgs() {
      let length = this.images.length;

      if (this.images.length < 5) {
        for (let i = 5; i > length; i--) {
          let img = new Image();
          img.imageUrl = this.imagesPlaceholder[i - 1];
          img.imageType = 'placeholder';
          this.images.push(img)
        }
      };
    }
  
    sortImgs(a, b) {
      // sort images accroding to the priority

      const imgA = a.priority;
      const imgB = b.priority;

      let comparison = 0;
      if (imgA > imgB) {
        comparison = 1;
      } else if (imgA < imgB) {
        comparison = -1;
      }
      return comparison;
    }

    onEditImages() {
      this.rearrangeImgs();
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalEditBrandImagesComponent, {
        width: '600px',
        maxHeight: '90vh',
        autoFocus: false,
        disableClose: true,
        data: {
          images: this.images,
          companyId: this.companyBrand.id
        }
      });

      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(dialogResult => {

      });

      dialogRef.componentInstance.onSave.subscribe((res) => {
        this.images = res;
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you rearranging the order in the parent? Do you need the 'reference' to the original array for something? If not, simply slice the original array after rearranging, and the child should pick it up.

You could probably also inject ChangeDetectorRef, and run detectChanges() - that should do the trick as well.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: yes the order is saved in database and when reorder it must be updated in database so i can get it from the parent and inject it as input in the child again

Comment: You have several methods that touch `images`. So, style don't apply after calling what method?

Comment: after onSave emmiter

Comment: Are you sure that content and order of the data in `res` and `this.images` different on `onSave()` called? Could you provide that data of `res` and `this.images`?

Comment: no after on save they are the same